# How to end Bluetooth pairing

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I want to end pairing between 2 cc2541 module, but when 2 modules are pair no
 AT-command executed and I cant end the pairing.
How can I end the connection?

Comment: How you programming the cc2541?

Answer (score 0):

I did this in my project by connect power of BT to digital pin of Arduino, and when need to stop pairing, just set the digital pin to low. may be this way will help you